# How can I generate and export the support structure for an object as a mesh?

Tags: 3d-models, support-structures

I want to render a visual of an mesh I created with a real support structure that a 3d printer would print. I haven't had any luck in finding a way to do this. Is there a program (ideally free) that can generate the proper support structure and export it into a mesh format, like .stl or .obj ?

Comment: Why do you need export as object or STL? if the gcode has all data to be printed and previewed before printing if desired.

Comment: @FernandoBaltazar I want to render the original object and the support structure in my 3D program. I'm trying to create a graphic that shows a real support structure for an object, and I want to have full control over how I compose the scene.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could try [Meshmixer](http://www.meshmixer.com) its free and the supports generated with it are embedded into the 3D model.

[Here](http://www.instructables.com/id/Meshmixer-Generate-Supports/) you can find a reference on Meshmixer supports. Meshmixer is well known for making custom supports for complex 3D models.